# Cannot use results of an api call in conversation

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to use the results of an api call in conversation but haven't been able to pass the results so that I can use them in conv.ask.  In the example here, I am able to log the "wind inner" but when I try to use it in conv.ask, I get "undefined."  I know it is a scoping issue, but I haven't been able to solve it.  Thanks!

```
app.intent('weather', (conv) => {

  var url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/"+apiKey+"/yesterday/q/55417.json";

  var request = http.get(url, function (response)  {

    var buffer = "",
      data,
      history;

    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
      buffer += chunk;
    });

    response.on("end", function (err) {

      console.log(buffer);
      console.log("\n");
      data = JSON.parse(buffer);
      history = data.history;

      var wind = (history.dailysummary[0].maxwspdi);

      console.log("wind inner: ", wind);//this works

    });
  });

  conv.ask("the wind speed is" + wind + "miles per hour");

  //unable to get the wind variable to be defined ouside the api call

});
```

Comment: You need to use a promise to wait until your API call is complete before sending the response back.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  While it may be a good idea to do this (use a promise) I think I have a context or scoping problem because I've been able to get this to work with a different app w/o using a promise.  I feel like I need to call the api function in the app/conv context but I don't know how to do this.  thx!  I tried request() but evidently this isn't the name of the function I want to call.

Comment: You need to use a Promise, otherwise the code will execute immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a Promise to return asynchronous responses. Additionally, make sure you wait until you get the response data to generate your text-to-speech. Here's a snippet that should work.

```es6
app.intent('weather', (conv) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/"+apiKey+"/yesterday/q/55417.json";
    const request = http.get(url, function (response)  {
      var buffer = "",
        data,
        history;

       response.on("data", function (chunk) {
         buffer += chunk;
       });

       response.on("end", function (err) {
         console.log(buffer);
         console.log("\n");
         data = JSON.parse(buffer);
         history = data.history;
         const wind = (history.dailysummary[0].maxwspdi);
         console.log("wind inner: ", wind);//this works
         conv.ask("the wind speed is" + wind + "miles per hour");
         resolve();
      });
    });
  });
});
```